# Indian residing in Tbilisi, Georgia visiting Turkey

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, turkey, georgia-country

I am an Indian citizen residing in Georgia with a temporary residence permit. Do I need a visa to visit Turkey?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you will need a visa. [Turkey](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa) doesn't seem to care about your status in Georgia. Just in case you happen to have a visa from a Schengen country or an [OECD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organisation_for_Economic_Co-operation_and_Development#Current_members) country, you can use their e-Visa system which seems to be a quicker way to go about it.

> India: Diplomatic passport holders are exempt from visa for their
>   travels to Turkey up to 90 days. Ordinary, Special and Service
>   passport holders are required to have visa to enter Turkey. Ordinary,
>   Special and Service passport holders with a valid Schengen or OECD
>   member's visa or residence permit may get their single entry e-Visas
>   valid for one month via the website [www.evisa.gov.tr](http://www.evisa.gov.tr), provided that
>   they meet certain conditions.